# How to hide item

Tags: swift, swiftui

I wanted to allow users to be able to hide their plans. In the code below, I wrote it, however, I can't change the label of the swipe. I would like to change delete to hide in the app, however, I could not find a way. So, I used the swipeActions, however, I am getting the error. `Value of type 'ForEach<[Plan], Int, NavigationLink<Text, some View>>' has no member 'swipeActions'`.

```
ForEach(plans_controller.plans) { plan in
                    
      NavigationLink(destination: planView()) {
          Text(plan.name)
      }
}.onDelete(perform: self.deleteRow)
```

Edit: Anyone who is having the problem, I used the following link to hide it. https://medium.com/swlh/how-to-delete-a-cell-by-clicking-a-button-in-swiftui-92c302d9c2e3

Answer (score 1):

Try putting `.swipeActions` *inside* the `ForEach`, not outside.

For example:

```
ForEach(plans_controller.plans) { plan in
    NavigationLink(destination: planView()) {
        Text(plan.name)
    }
    .swipeActions { ... }
}
.onDelete(perform: self.deleteRow)
```

... not:

```
ForEach(plans_controller.plans) { plan in
    NavigationLink(destination: planView()) {
        Text(plan.name)
    }
}
.onDelete(perform: self.deleteRow)
.swipeActions { ... }
```

Comment: Thank you for the help. Currently, I am getting an error ```Value of type 'NavigationLink<Text, some View>' has no member 'swipeActions'```

Comment: @Daniel do you have Xcode 13 Beta? `swipeActions` won't work in Xcode 12

Comment: would I need to update my Xcode to make work?

Comment: @Daniel yes. You can get Xcode 13 beta [here](https://developer.apple.com/download/).